# Can I move controls to inside a groupbox without loss the control's attributes?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, controls

On Visual Studio in the GUI designer, If I do in a `Control` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> inside a `GroupBox` control the information like the events I defined to this control isn't preserved. Can I copy it and keep its attributes?

I need to move some controls I don't want to define again the control's attributes/again of them.

Comment: Just move them instead of trying to cut/paste.  You can select more than one control before moving.

Comment: Also noteworthy: Moving with the mouse will chnage the parent if you move the controls out of the former parent. Moving by keyboard will not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drag the controls into the group box directly using mouse. By using dragging and dropping method visual studio will not remove the object from the parent container. So, you will not lose the events handling and attributes by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Using Visual Studio 2015, dragging a control into a groupbox removes the control from the databinding.currencyManager.Bindings list thus disconnecting it from the dataset. You can verify this using:

```
        For i = 0 To myBindingSource.CurrencyManager.Bindings.Count - 1
             MsgBox(myBindingSource.CurrencyManager.Bindings(i).Control.Name.ToString)
        Next
```

Comment: Yep, I noticied that most (if not all, not confirmed) properties are lost.